# Changing a Class String variable through another Class - Not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Question: I want to press the "Manipulator" class button to change the ChangeValue's value variable to Manipulator's manipulatorName value, which isn't occurring. What have I done wrong?**

I have a class (called ChangeValue) that initialises with an empty string name. I'm doing this since it will be displayed on the website as "Empty" for now. However, when I click a another class (called Manipulator) it should change ChangeValue, which isn't occurring. The ChangeValue's value is always set to "Empty", despite when I click the button.

My code:

```
export class ChangeValue extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: " "
        };
    }
    render() {
        var currentValue = null;
        if (this.value == null) {
            currentValue = "Empty"
        } else {
            currentValue = this.value
        }
        return (
            currentValue
        )
    }
}
```

```
export class Manipulator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            manipulatorName: "New Value"
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>
        <ChangeValue value = {this.state.manipulatorName} />
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

I based the "ChangeValue value" line based off what I was reading from Stack and it may be there is an issue with Parent/Children, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on here as to why it's not working.

You can clean up your `ChangeValue` component, as it doesn't actually use any state. It only needs to use the value of the prop passed to it from the `Manipulator`, so therefore can be converted into a stateless 'dumb' function based component.

```
function ChangeValue(props) {
    return props.value || "Empty"
}
```

Or if you still want it as a class so you can add some state in later...

```
export class ChangeValue extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.value || "Empty"
    }
}
```

These will both have the same output. They will return the value of `props.value` if it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), [OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) (`||`) return the word "Empty" if `props.value` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

The `Manipulator` class needs a little bit of work also. It currently sets up a `handleClick` method but doesn't define it. It should probably look something like this...

```
export class Manipulator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          manipulatorName: undefined
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
             manipulatorName: "New Value After Click"
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <ChangeValue value={this.state.manipulatorName} />
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

This will initially render a button with the text "Empty" as the `manipulatorName` is **falsy**. Upon clicking the button, the button text should then change to say "New Value After Click".

I hope this helps, if it doesn't quite fit with what you're trying to achieve, please comment or update the question with some further details.

**UPDATE**

Here is a [working example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-shape-7hc6u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Thanks for the great help aljhaining, much appreciated. I got it working with your help. I think I understand much better now what exactly I've been doing wrong now regarding my code in general.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.